# Trying ".Insert Shift:=xlDown" on Excel VBA gives error on specific PC

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing an error while trying to **copy and insert an entire line using VBA**.

What is strange is that my code has always worked, and now it only gives an error in a specific PC at the office.

Let's say I run this:

```
Sub test_debug()

With Selection.EntireRow
    .Copy
    .Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With

End Sub
```

It works on one PC, and gives this at the other:

[image]

It translates to something like: "Insert method of class Range failed."

Both PCs have Office 365 on version 2004 (build 12730.20250).

I tried copying the working file and running it on the other PC, no success.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try to avoid `selection`

Comment: @Dorian it's not used in the production code, I wrote this code to help anyone trying to replicate or debug

Comment: It won't make a difference, but `Range.Insert` calls for `xlShiftDown`, not `xlDown` btw.

Comment: @Lucas Your code Is working for me, be sure that selected selection isn't empty

Comment: @BigBen didn't know that. It still erros, but thank you

Comment: @Dorian I checked and it's not empty. Thank you for trying the code

Comment: give a try to my answer

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue ?

Comment: Hi @Dorian, it suddenly stopped giving error. I don't know what happened and I have never seen an issue like that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lucas did you try my answer

Comment: @Dorian yes, tried when you posted it. Didn't solve the problem